# Help with making Resume

Tags: cv

I am re doing my resume to change the format and want it to look something like this:

[image]

If anyone knows of a template I can tinker with that will look something like this please send it my way or if there is a business where I can pay someone to do this for me let me know.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{microtype}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em}

% indentsection style, used for sections that aren't already in lists
% that need indentation to the level of all text in the document
\newenvironment{indentsection}[1]%
{\begin{list}{}%
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
    \item[]%
}
{\end{list}}

% opposite of above; bump a section back toward the left margin
\newenvironment{unindentsection}[1]%
{\begin{list}{}%
    {\setlength{\leftmargin}{-0.5#1}}%
    \item[]%
}
{\end{list}}

% format two pieces of text, one left aligned and one right aligned
\newcommand{\headerrow}[2]
{\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    #1 &
    #2 \\
\end{tabular*}}

% make "C++" look pretty when used in text by touching up the plus signs
\newcommand{\CPP}
{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.22ex}{\footnotesize\bf ++}}

% and the actual content starts here
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \textbf{name}}

address\ \ \textbullet
\ \ address
\\
phone\ \ \textbullet
\ \ email
\end{center}



\hrule
\vspace{-0.4em}
\subsection*{Experience}

\begin{itemize}
    \parskip=0.1em

    \item
    \headerrow
        {\textbf{UCLA REU}}
        {\textbf{Los Angeles, CA}}
    \\
    \headerrow
        {\emph{Research Assistant }}
        {\emph{Summer 2014}}
    \begin{itemize*}
        \item Research in Microscopy and Image processing.
        \item Led team to meet the research project deadline and wrote research paper on results.
        \item Wrote algorithms in Matlab to improve upon state-of-the-art image segmentation techniques.
        \item Published in Vol. 11 no. 3 June 2017 regular issue in Inverse Problems and Imaging (IPI).
    \end{itemize*}

    \item
    \headerrow
        {\textbf{Business Statistics Tutor for Dr. Robertas Gabrys at USC}}
        {\textbf{Los Angeles, CA}}
    \\
    \headerrow
        {\emph{Statistics Tutor}}
        {\emph{2011 - 2013}}
    \begin{itemize*}
        \item Tutor students in statistical methods for business analysis; data exploration and description; sampling distributions; estimation; hypothesis; hypothesis testing; simple and multiple regression; model building, and computer applications.
    \end{itemize*}

    \item
    \headerrow
        {\textbf{Probability Theory Research for Dr. Quentin Berger}}
        {\textbf{Los Angeles, CA}}
    \\
    \headerrow
        {\emph{Research Assistant}}
        {\emph{2012 - 2013}}
    \begin{itemize*}
        \item Wrote a Matlab program that calculated the pore fluid pressure and its evolution over time within a time fault zone.
        \item The program consists of a 2-dimensional section plane of the fault showing the contacts between the two plates modeled using percolation theory.
        \item Two types of fluid pressure were considered: the pore fluid pressure and the surface fluid pressure. 
    \end{itemize*}

    \item
    \headerrow
    {\textbf{UBS Private Wealth Management}}
    {\textbf{Los Angeles, CA}}
    \\
    \headerrow
    {\emph{Financial Analyst Intern}}
    {\emph{2011 - 2012}}
    \begin{itemize*}
        \item Worked directly under partner, Dan Gallagher Group ($185$B), specializing in the financial needs of wealthy individuals. 
        \item Evaluated portfolio structures, and suggested changes that included positions in fixed income, alternative investments, derivatives, and equities.
        \item Networked with investment managers, research analysts, and money managers to obtain perspectives on financial markets and individual securities.  
    \end{itemize*}
\end{itemize}


\hrule
\vspace{-0.4em}
\subsection*{Education}

\begin{itemize}
    \parskip=0.1em

    \item 
    \headerrow
        {\textbf{Florida State University}}
        {\textbf{Tallahassee, Florida}}
    \\
    \headerrow
        {\emph{Department of Mathematics, Masters in Financial Mathematics \  \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \textbf{GPA: 3.6}}}
        {\emph{2015-2017}}
    \begin{itemize*}
        \item Passed Measure Theory and Computational Mathematics Qualifying Exam.
        \item Relevant coursework: Scientific Computing, Financial Engineering 1 and 2, Computational Mathematics 1 and 2, and Machine Learning.
    \end{itemize*}

        \item 
        \headerrow
        {\textbf{University of Southern California}}
        {\textbf{Los Angeles, CA}}
        \\
        \headerrow
        {\emph{Bachelors of Science in Business Administration, and Mathematical Finance}}
        {\emph{2011 - 2013}}


\end{itemize}


\hrule
\vspace{-0.4em}
\subsection*{Core Technical Skills}

\begin{indentsection}{\parindent}
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\begin{description*}
    \item[Languages:]
     \CPP, \LaTeX,R, SAS, Matlab,Python, Bloomberg Certified 
\end{description*}
\end{indentsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post what you've tried so far (some code). There are tons of resume classes out there.

Comment: What you have posted looks almost like in the picture, but with appropriate spacing. The text in the image shown is cramped. What is missing from your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharelatex has many CV templates [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/cies-breijs-resume/) looks like the one you have posted and can be downloaded or edited online

[image]